# Can you extract the file object of an hdf5 using a group object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, hdf5, h5py

I opened an hdf5 file in ipython, using

```
import h5py as h5
f = h5.File("fname.h5", "r")
```

Then I accessed a group in that file

```
g1 = f['group1']
```

Then I accidentally overwrote `f` with another file. The first file is still open, and I can access stuff from `g1`, but I can't access any other groups in `f`. Is there a way to use `g1` to get the file object back? Of course I can just close and re-open the file, but I want to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `file` attribute of your group:

```
f = g1.file
```

As per the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#reference) for `Group` attributes:

> **file**
>  File instance in which this group resides.

Comment: Yeah this is probably better than `parent` in case you are multiple groups in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question is worthy of existing, but I found the answer. Groups have a `parent` attribute that points to the parent. To get the original file, just use `f = g1.parent`.

edit: actually, while this allows you to access groups from `/`, the new `f` would reference the *group* `/`, not the file. So you can't close the file using `f`, or access any other file attributes.